# C++ and XAML - Numeric Input from Textbox

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is my first forum post here. I'm new to c++ (been using MATLAB for years) and I am using visual studio's UWP template, creating the gui in the designer view, and trying to get inputs to do things in the background (I'm trying to make it matlab I guess lol). Every time I try to do this, it tella me that my inputs (input1->Text for example) are strings not double and I don't know how to get numeric inputs. New to this and very confused. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: You can simply cast the `String` to `Double`if your requirement is as simple as that.. you can go through this link for `Double.TryParse()` which provides a safe way to do the conversion : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not clear you need C++/WinRT or C++/CX,I give the code for **C++/CX** by default.You can try the code below.

```
String^ text = MyTextBox->Text;
std::wstring ws1(text->Data());​
double num = std::stod(ws1);
```

Comment: Sorry I never got a notification that my question was answered! That worked! Thanks x 1 million! Then after I did the maths, I output the result (total) like this: 
 Platform::String^ x = total.ToString();
 output->Text = x;